# MongoDB Compass does not allow ObjectId() while populating DB with "Insert Document" feature?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am using MongoDB Compass version 1.25.0.

I was trying to insert a document shared by one of my colleague using the "Insert Document" feature of the MongoDB Compass.

But, it's showing that the document is not in correct format.
[image]

I think it is validating JSON format and ObjectId() is not a valid JSON value.

I am aware that Compass would create ObjectId() automatically but I want to pass it explicitly.

I resorted to the Shell and I was able to insert the document.

My question is does MongoDB Compass allow entering ObjectId() from the UI?
If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: "asdf" as seen in the image is _not_ a valid value. ObjectId constructor takes a hexadecimal value of the format shown in the docs: [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/index.html).

Comment: My bad it was just an example. Updated the question.

Comment: The document view is of JSON format. You need to use [Extended JSON format](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/index.html#bson.ObjectId) for the `ObjectId`.

Comment: When using the format you suggested `{"$oid":"5d505646cf6d4fe581014ab2"}` it shows `BSON field 'insert.documents.0' is the wrong type 'objectId', expected type 'object'`

Comment: See the documentation for [Compass - Insert](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/documents/insert).

Comment: Already went through it. it says if not provided "_id" will be inserted automatically. It does not say how to insert ObjectId.

Comment: @prasad_ I was able to solve it. It was just a matter of syntax. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to insert a document with ObjectId using below syntax:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "60261ccf416a1ed478d7357a"
    }
}
```

I found that the documentation of a bit off in clarifying how the $oid is supposed to be used.
At least for someone beginner like me.

[image]